# Cant boot into Window 8 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot

After i install Ubuntu, i cant boot into windows  anymore, I already tried boot repair, and grub update, and it doesnt work. Please help

Link from Boot repair.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9615598/

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: When? u mean during boot or when using ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to have to inform you of this, but after reading the boot repair report, it would appear that... unless of course you have two hard drives and one has been disconnected, you no longer have a windows partition.

In other words it would appear that when you installed Ubuntu, you chose the option marked "use the entire drive" replacing windows, instead of the option marked, "install side by side".

All I can say is that now that you have made that mistake, you probably will never do it again.  Now you have two choices:

1) You can continue to use Ubuntu which I assure you is much safer and more reliable than Windows 8.

or

2) You can re-install Windows 8 on your drive and then if you still want a dual boot, you can repeat the procedure this time choosing the correct option.

Comment: oh noooooooooooooo. I didnt do a backup. Can i restore all the software and application from Windows 8?

Comment: No, not without a TARDIS anyway.  The time to do backups is prior to obliterating data.